# Call a GraphQL mutation on connected objects (case: React and AWS)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-mutation

I have created this GraphQL schema and passed it to AppSync via Amplify:

```
type Member @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Team @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  members: [Member]
}
```

and AWS Amplify has generated the following mutation for team update:

```
export const updateTeam = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdateTeam(
    $input: UpdateTeamInput!
    $condition: ModelTeamConditionInput
  ) {
    updateTeam(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      name
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm wanting to update the Team via:

```
  const doSomething = async (id) => {
    try {
      const team = teams[id];
      team.title = // new title

      // cut off automatically added bits

      const teamData = await API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(updateTeam, { input: team })
      );

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Mutation failed`, error);
    }
  };
```

I am reading the `team` successfully and I can see that `members` is a part of the team object. However, it raises an error:

```
message: "The variables input contains a field name 'members' that is not defined for input object type 'UpdateTeamInput' "
```

Where and how should I fix this? I mean do I have to go with something like:

```
...
graphqlOperation(updateTeam, { input: team, members: team.members })
...
```

although I'm not touching the `members` object in `team[id]`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't define Member as **input** type in your graphql schema instead you have defined it as **type** type.

Define member input type like this:

```
input MemberInput {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

in your graphql schema, it would work then.

Note that if your types are custom than arguments in graphql should be of **input** type and the return values of **type** type.

Comment: This is problematic as the "model" directive cannot be used on input objects. Amplify CLI will explicitly throw an error and blocks the push operation.

Comment: @Manny then declare one more input type and use that in further schema, please check updated answer